# Archiving multiple targets on XCode and Building Multiple IPA files in one go (scripts or commands wanted)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I've been looking but have no luck.  I tried using Edit Schemes and create a "All" target but it resulted in a single bundle combining all items when I create an Archive.

Basically my app uses a single code base but with different localized contents.  Each app has its on bundle ID, app name, etc.  So I wanted to make releasing easier by using the minimal amount of actions to arrive at multiple IPA files.  Ideally this would be a script, a few commands, or just several clicks along the way.

Currently I have 10 languages.  So I'll have to select each of the language targets, click Product > Archive, then for each language click Distribute and build the IPA file in the Organizer.

Advice is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: !0 builds for 10 languages?  Are the localisation facilities in iOS not adequate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start looking at Jenkins to get the job done. It can create an ipa for every target you want... [Start automating your build via Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org)

For automating the distribution process, i received a mail from Apple last week about meta data delivery with Transporter. It's a command line tool. Sounds interesting...